# Include value of current user in simple_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

Trying to prepopulate a form in Rails using simple_form and devise.

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, input_html: {value: "<%= current_user.email %>"} %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Create password for this email" %>
  </div>
```

Specifically with this line input_html: {value: "<%= current_user.email %>"}. Checking https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form I can see that input_html + value can be the way to go, but it returns an error every time I pass an attribute of the user currently logged in.

syntax error, unexpected '>'
/path/app/views/devise/passwords/_forgotpassword.html.erb:12: unknown regexp options - dv

[image]

Comment: could you include the file row 12 from `app/views/devise/passwords/_forgotpassword.html.erb` thanks

Comment: It's the one you have in the code snippet     <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, input_html: {value: "<%= current_user.email %>"} %>

Comment: Can you try `{ value: "#{current_user.email}" }`?